# IE rendering issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, html

My website is not rendering properly in IE browser and in other browsers like chrome, safari and firefox it displays fine. I am not sure if any div has a problem or is it the style sheet.

**Below is the url for which I am talking about:** 
http://unyforme.com/demo/

Not sure what is causing the bad layout in IE.

Please advise if any one finds a clue and/or point out some thing for me?

Comment: It would be highly helpful if you give the SO community information on how you did your site, like are you using HTML5 and CSS, adding any plugins, flash. Your question do not tell us enough to give you a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your DOCTYPE must must must be the first line, or IE renders in quirks mode.

Remove everything before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Also, to make the site load significantly quicker, move all your javascript to the bottom, just before the end of your `body` tag.

Comment: Hello Rich, Awesome. You really saved my day. :)